# jQuery ui options not working

Tags: javascript

hope someone can help, I have a jQuery ui accordion working OK, but I cannot get any options I set to work. I'm not using modules for this, adding jQuery UI in my library, and the accordion itself works so I know all scripts are loading OK. My library file has:

```
ui-accordion:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/site/min/jqui-accordion-min.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.ui.accordion
```

The library is then attached in a template file. My `jqui-accordion-min.js` has:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.basic = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        $("#accordion" ).accordion({ heightStyle: "content" });
    }
  };
}(jQuery, Drupal));
```

I've tried other options too, including `autoHeight: "false"`.

Is there something wrong with my jQuery, or do I need to load something else?

Comment: The format is incorrect. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I've updated the question after correcting formatting to Drupal spec from your link - thank you. However, options are still not having an effect, accordion still works correctly as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found the answer [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/) - I only had part of the option set correctly; here's the full jQuery:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.basic = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        $("#accordion" ).accordion({ 
            heightStyle: "content"  
        });

        // Getter
        var heightStyle = $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "heightStyle" );

        // Setter
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "heightStyle", "content" );
    }
  };
}(jQuery, Drupal));
```

My bad for skim-reading the API, I saw 'Initialize the accordion' then 'Or set...' (and so ignored the next bit) instead of 'Get or Set'. Wasn't clear if the 'or' means you could use the 'getter' or the 'setter' instead. But I used both as written and it works now. :)